# How do I pass index number to a react class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need help passing data "locationpos"= index of my Locations[]  from function to class. I'm very new to React and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**ERROR**

Failed to compile
./src/components/data.js
Line 20:30:  'locationpos' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

```js
class Data {
  constructor(locationpos) {
    this.locationpos=locationpos;
    this.updateData();
  }

  getTimes(date = null) {
    date = date === null ? moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') : date;
    var data = this.getData();
    return data ? data[date] : [];
  }
  

  getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.myData[locationpos];
  }
```

```js
function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);
  
 const [locationState] = useState(localization());
 const handleClick = event => {
    window.focus();
    notification.close(event.target.tag);
  };

  const openNav = () => {
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "100%";
  };

  const closeNav = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line
const locationpos  = locations.indexOf(locations[locationState]);
const _data = useRef(new Data(locationpos));

  const getTimes = () => _data.current.getTimes();
```

Comment: Try to change it to `this.locationpos`

Comment: thankyou work fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your data class, you need to use the instance variable as `this.locationPos`

```
  getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.myData[this.locationpos];
  }
```